# How to display variables' special characters in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How does one properly display special characters ("(", "ë", periods as commas, etc.) used in column names within a ggplot graphic?

My csv's column line looks like this:

```
r, á/b, ő/é, w/s (0.3), w/s (0.2), bins
```

And I'd like, for instance, the 4th variable to be displayed (in the ggplot legend), as "w/s (0.3)".

Here's my code:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

fileName = paste("/2.csv", sep = "") # test file available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2egxbuwwbba2q9/2.csv?dl=0

mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE)

dataM = melt(mydata,c("bins"))
ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x= bins, y=value, colour=variable, size = variable)) +
geom_line(alpha = .9) +
scale_colour_manual(breaks=c("r","á/b","ő/é","w/s (0.3)","w/s (0.2)"), values=c("green","orange","blue","pink","yellow")) +
#scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 7) +
scale_size_manual(breaks=c("r","á/b","ő/é","w/s (0.3)","w/s (0.2)"), values=c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)) +
theme_bw() +
theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
legend.key = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank()) +
scale_y_continuous("D", expand=c(0,0)) + 
scale_x_continuous("E", expand=c(0,0)) +
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Which produces this:

[image]

We can see how the legend wrongly display special characters. Any quick way (or not-so-quick way) to fix this?

(I have other questions about this graphics, but I believe it is preferred to ask a new complete question, which I'll do right now)

Comment: this may depend on platform (presumably MacOS in your case), locale, and/or output device (Quartz).  Maybe try one of the output devices in the `Cairo` package and see if it helps?

Comment: It is OS X indeed, I'll check Cairo out (haven't heard of it yet). Thanks!

Comment: actually, I think all you might need would be `read.csv(file,check.names=FALSE)`

Comment: This works perfectly!!! Thank you so much! Can you please convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is include `check.names=FALSE` in your `read.csv()` call; the special characters in your header are getting converted when the data is read in (see `?make.names` for more information).

I was initially a little confused by your question because I assumed the problem was with accented characters such as ë, whereas in fact letters are *not* getting messed up -- it's only non-alphanumeric characters that are replaced by dots (also, strings starting with a numeric value would have "X" prepended).